# Statistical team game information

Tags: sql

I have two tables: Teams and Matches. Teams table records the ID and name of the team, and Matches table records the ID and number of goals scored by both teams.

Here is an example:

| team_id | team_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Liverpool |
| 2 | Arsenal |
| 3 | Manchester |

| home_team_id | away_team_id | home_team_goals | away_team_goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

Write a SQL to report team information. The winning team gets `3 points`, while the losing team gets `0 point`. In the event of a tie, both teams get `1 point`.

Each row of the result table should contain:

- team_name
- games_played - The number of matches played
- points - The total points the team has so far.
- goals_scored - The total number of goals scored by the team across all matches.
- goals_against - The total number of goals scored by opponent teams against this team across all matches.
- goals_difference - The result of goals_scored - goals_against.

Return the result table ordered by `points` **in descending order**. If two or more teams have the same points, order them by `goals_difference` **in descending order**. If there is still a tie, order them by `team_name` **in lexicographical order**.

For the above example, the results should be:

| team_name | games_played | points | goals_scored | goals_against | goals_difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Liverpool | 4 | 8 | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| Arsenal | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | -1 |
| Manchester | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | -1 |

I tried the following query in my PieCloudDB Database, although it can get correct results, the execution time is very long when the table data becomes large. Is there a faster query method?

```
select team_name,count(*) games_played,
3*(sum(g1)+sum(g2))+ sum(g3) points,
sum(goals_scored) goals_scored,
sum(goals_against) goals_against,
sum(goals_scored-goals_against) goals_difference
from (select *,
case when home_team_id = team_id then home_team_goals  when away_team_id = team_id then away_team_goals else 0 end as goals_scored,
case when home_team_id = team_id then away_team_goals  when away_team_id = team_id then home_team_goals else 0 end as goals_against,
case when home_team_id = team_id and  home_team_goals > away_team_goals then 1 else 0 end as g1,
case when away_team_id = team_id and  home_team_goals < away_team_goals then 1 else 0 end as g2,
case when home_team_goals = away_team_goals then 1 else 0 end as g3
from Teams t ,Matches m
where team_id in (home_team_id,away_team_id)) a 
group by 1 
order by points desc,goals_difference desc,team_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what PieCloudDB is but I learned that it is compatible with PostgreSQL and I tried the following query in PostgreSQL. You can use `union all`, I have tested that the query speed is much faster than before.

```
with T as (select home_team_id,away_team_id, home_team_goals,away_team_goals 
  from Matches 
  union all 
  select away_team_id as home_team_id,home_team_id as away_team_id, away_team_goals as home_team_goals,home_team_goals as away_team_goals 
  from Matches) 
  select team_name,games_played,points,goals_scored,goals_against,(goals_scored - goals_against) as goals_difference 
  from (select home_team_id, sum(home_team_goals) as goals_scored, 
  sum(case when home_team_goals>away_team_goals then 3 
           when home_team_goals=away_team_goals then 1 else 0 end) as points, count(*) as games_played, sum(away_team_goals) as goals_against 
  from T group by home_team_id) A join Teams ts on A.home_team_id=ts.team_id 
  order by points desc,goals_difference desc,team_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to think about reorganizing the table into something more useful.  Here, the inner query returns a list of each game played for each team, with the points THEY scored, and the points the opponent scored.  Then it becomes much easier to compute the stats you need.

This does everything except look up the team name in the names table, and I believe it should scale well.

```
SELECT team, 
    COUNT(for) AS games, 
    SUM(SIGN(for-against)+1+(for>against)) AS points,
    SUM(for) AS goals_scored,
    SUM(against) AS goals_against,
    SUM(for)-SUM(against) AS goal_difference
FROM (
    SELECT home_team_id AS team, home_team_goals AS for, away_team_goals AS against FROM matches
    UNION ALL
    SELECt away_team_id AS team, away_team_goals AS for, home_team_goals AS against FROM matches
)
GROUP BY team;
```

Output:

```
1|4|8|5|3|2
2|4|4|4|5|-1
3|4|4|3|4|-1
```

I'm willing to bet there's a better way to compute the total points, but this one does the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I get an error: `operator does not exist: double precision + boolean`, maybe `SIGN(for-against)+1+(for>against)` doesn't work for my database.

Comment: Possibly.  You might be able to use a "CASE WHEN" there to replace the whole clause.